# webstart launches run jre, is there workaround?

Tags: java, java-web-start

My application is started by webstart, and it must run with jre6. But my customer's PC, for some reason, installs both jre6 and jre7. To specify jre6, I invoke my application using following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaws https://kong/QoSAC/qosac/lsm.jnlp
```

As you see, I use jre6's webstart. But it seems the webstart still invoke javaw of jre7:

[image]

In my jnlp file, I have set:

```
<j2se version="1.6">
```

Why webstart still choose jre7?

But if I put everything on local, and use the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaws c:\appdir\lsm.jnlp
```

This way it works fine, jre6 is chosen by webstart.

Is this a bug of webstart? Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed your jnlp. In particular, adding the version of Java you want in your jnlp should solve your issue:

```
<j2se version="1.6">
```

You can read more [here about webstart versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).